# SONICMQ: 8.5: No space in multi-connection accept queue

Tags: sonicmq

Wondering if someone could help me with this.

I am getting some errors in Domain Manager & Domain Manager Backup log files as below:

```
[16/11/23 00:28:19] ID=DIRECTORY SERVICE (info) Replication connection TCP://hostname:22516 (re)established
[16/11/23 00:28:19] ID=DIRECTORY SERVICE (warning) Replication connection TCP://hostmane:22516 lost: No space in multi-connection accept queue
[16/11/23 00:28:22] ID=DIRECTORY SERVICE (info) Replication connection TCP://hostmane:2600 (re)established
[16/11/23 00:28:22] ID=DIRECTORY SERVICE (warning) Replication connection TCP://hostname:2600 lost: No space in multi-connection accept queue
[16/11/23 00:28:23] ID=DIRECTORY SERVICE (info) Replication connection TCP://hostname:22516 (re)established
[16/11/23 00:28:23] ID=DIRECTORY SERVICE (warning) Replication connection TCP://hostmane:22516 lost: No space in multi-connection accept queue
```

The errors are continuously appearing. How could I resolve these. I cannot find any documentation around this.

Comment: Are you using sdm to deploy or did you configure it manually? it won't be easy to find only with this little amount of log.
Add some more tracing and update your post.

Comment: Hi Chan, Thanks for your reply. I added some tracking and here are the messages in the log files:

Comment: Unable to add details here. Where can I post the logs ?

Comment: you can edit your original post